# Finding a plane parallel to a line

Tags: vectors

So I've been stuck on this question.
Find a plane that will have no points of intersection with the line $L1.$
$L1$ passes through the point $P(1,−2,0)$ and parallel to the vector $q = (1,−1,3).$ Find a plane that will have no points of intersection with the line $L1.$

So straight away I think, find a plane parallel to the line $L1$
But the normal to a plane $(Ax+By+Cz)$ is $(A,B,C)$ if I've got that right.
Where is the hole in my knowledge? And how would I go about this correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Now, are you trying to find a plane **normal** to the given line, as you say in your title, or are you trying to find a plane **parallel** to the line as you say in the body?  A plane normal to the vector (1, -1, 3), containing the point (1, -2, 0) is (x- 1)- (y+ 2)+ 3z= 0.  But there are an infinite number of planes **parallel** to a given line containing a given point!  Consider the line the line through the given point parallel to the give line.  Take any plane containing this second line.  One of those planes **contains** the given line but all the rest are parallel.

Comment: In order for there to be no point of intersection, the plane must be parallel to the given line. There are infinitely many possibilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choos any vector not parallel to $(1,-1,3)$ such as $(1,0,0)$

The vector perpendicular to both of these, i.e. The cross product is $(0,3,1)$

This is the normal to the plane.

The equation of the plane is therefore $3y+z=d$

Now we choose $d$ so that the point $(1,-2,0)$ does not lie on the plane, such as $d=0$ and you are done.

Comment: Ahhhh, so by creating a line that isn't parallel to $L1$ we can find the normal to both with the cross product, thus the equation of the plane!! This makes alot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

- determine a vector $n=(a,b,c)\perp q$
- consider the plane $ax+by+cz+d=0 \quad \parallel \quad L1$
- consider a point $Q\not \in L1$
- find $d$ by the condition $Q\in$ plane

Comment: So, I let some vector $v_1=(a,b,c)$ and do $v_1\cdot q=0$ to get $a-b+3c$ I don't understand where to go from there

Comment: take for example c=1b=1 a=4, we have infinitely many possibilities to choose that plane

Comment: It seems to be that I'm confused as to how the answer should be. As I keep putting $ax+bz+cz=D$ And this always gives a plane perpendicular. Sorry if it sound dumb, but I really can't seem to get my head around it.

Comment: Choosing whatever $n=(a,b,c) \perp L1$ we obtain a family of planes parallel to L1 (as d varies), the it suffices to chose d in such way te plane doesn't contain L1 itself

Answer (score 0):

the line $L_1$

- Passes through the point $P=(1,−2,0)$.
- Is parallel to the vector $\vec q = (1,−1,3).$

Find a plane that will have no points of intersection with the line $L_1.$

Create a vector perpendicular to $\vec q$, say $\vec v =(1,1,0)$. (Note $v \circ q = 0.)$

Then the point $Q = v+P = (2,-1,0)$ is not on the line $L_1$. (Note $P \ne Q.$)

The equation of the plane, $\pi$, that is perpendicular to the vector $\vec v$ and passes through the point $Q$, is

\begin{align}
   [(x,y,z)-Q] \circ \vec v &= 0 \\
   (x-1) + (y+2) &= 0 \\
   x+y &= -1
\end{align}

Since the plane and the line are both perpendicular to the line $\overleftrightarrow{PQ}$ at points $P$ and $Q$ respectively, then the line and the plane are parallel.